# Recieving Data From Arduino in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino

I am trying to conrolling my object with button which is added arduino.
I have Funduino to manage that.There are 4 button on it but I am going to use 3 of them.But I coulnd't get data from my serial port.

So I wonder if I may request  from you guys to give me some tips about how can I do to getting whether those 3 buttons are pressed or not in c# interface.

Here my codes in arduino:

```
// Store the Arduino pin associated with each input
const byte PIN_BUTTON_SELECT = 6; // Select button is triggered when joystick is                                                           pressed

const byte PIN_BUTTON_RIGHT = 3;
const byte PIN_BUTTON_UP = 2;
const byte PIN_BUTTON_DOWN = 4;
const byte PIN_BUTTON_LEFT = 5
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);

// Specify each pin connected to a pushbutton as an input.
// Also enable the Arduino's internal "pull-up" resistors
// for each pushbutton we want to read--this means the shield
// doesn't need to have resistors on it.
// Note that when a pull-up resistor is used on a pin the
// meaning of the values read are reversed compared to their
// usual meanings:
//    * HIGH = the button is not pressed
//    * LOW = the button is pressed  
pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_RIGHT, INPUT);  
digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_RIGHT, HIGH);

pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_LEFT, INPUT);  
digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_LEFT, HIGH);

pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_UP, INPUT);  
digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_UP, HIGH);

pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_DOWN, INPUT);  
digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_DOWN, HIGH);

pinMode(PIN_BUTTON_SELECT, INPUT);  
digitalWrite(PIN_BUTTON_SELECT, HIGH); 
 }


void loop() {


}
```

Comment: Is 9600 the correct baudrate?

Comment: yes it works on serial port

Comment: Did below answer work or do you need more information?

Comment: well thank you but that was not what I was trying to code.I need code for c#.Like I wanna get if some button,which is added arduino,is pressed start countdown or some function you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the read functionality in the loop method:

```
void loop() {
   // read the state of the pushbutton value:
   buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

   // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
   // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
   if (buttonState == HIGH) {
     // turn LED on:
     digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
   } else {
     // turn LED off:
     digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
   }
```